# LAME api for iOS - Setup

Tags: ios, mp3, lame, caf

I have seen a very few posts on this issue. Everything is explained in a vague manner. Is there a way to know on the step by step setup of LAME api for iOS (http://lame.sourceforge.net/). If anyone can be patient enough to explain on the set up of LAME iOS it will be awesome. Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Have you seen this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005598/looking-for-a-way-to-encode-mp3-on-iphone

Comment: [Use AAC](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/iPhoneExtAudioFileConvertTest/Introduction/Intro.html), it's supposed to be ["the successor" to MP3 anyway](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Audio_Coding) and it doesn't have the nasty licensing issues.